# Flutter: save list as favorite

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview

I have JSON data file that looks like this, as you can see the "attractions" is a list itself under each city:

```
[
    {
        "city": "text text text",
        "attractions": [
            "text text ",
            "text text"
        ],
    },
    {
        "city": "text text text",
        "attractions": [
            "text text",
            "text text",
        ],
    },
]
```

The following code is basically a listview builder that gets data from the above JSON. Now when the city is clicked it navigate to the next page where it shows a list of attractions in that city. As you can see form the code, there is an option to save cities in another page as favorite that can be shown in another list of saved favorites:

```
class Index extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IndexState createState() => _IndexState();
}
List data;
List<Cities> citylist = List();
List<Cities> citysavedlist = List();
int index;
class _IndexState extends State<Index> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: listView(),
    );
  }
  Future<String> fetchData() async {
    String data =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/data.json");
    final jsonResult = json.decode(data);
    this.setState(() {
      jsonResult
          .forEach((element) => citylist.add(new Cities.fromJson(element)));
    });
    return "Success!";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  listView() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: citylist == null ? 0 : citylist.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[_buildRow(index, citylist)],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRow(index, citylist) {
    final bool alreadySaved = citysavedlist.contains(citylist[index]);
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, left: 5.0, right: 5.0),
      child: Card(
        child: ListTile(
            title:
                Text(citylist[index].title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0)),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                alreadySaved ? Icons.star : Icons.star_border,
                color: alreadySaved ? Colors.blue : Colors.blue,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (alreadySaved) {
                    citysavedlist.remove(citylist[index]);
                  } else {
                    citysavedlist.add(citylist[index]);
                  }
                });
              },
            ), //subtitle: Text(subtitle),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => Detail(citylist[index])));
            }),
      ),
    );
  }


void _pushSaved() {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute<void>(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          final Iterable<ListTile> tiles = citysavedlist.map(
            (Cities pair) {
              return ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    pair.city,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Detail(pair)));
                  });
            },
          );

          final List<Widget> divided = ListTile.divideTiles(
            context: context,
            tiles: tiles,
          ).toList();
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Saved Suggestions'),
            ),
            body: ListView(children: divided),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is  model class :

```
List<Cities> citiesFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Cities>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Cities.fromJson(x)));
String citiesToJson(List<Cities> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Cities {
  Cities({
    this.city,
    this.attractions,
  });

  String city;
  List<String> attractions;

  factory Cities.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Cities(
        city: json["city"],
        attractions: List<String>.from(json["attractions"].map((x) => x)),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "city": city,
        "attractions": List<dynamic>.from(attractions.map((x) => x)),
      };
}
```

The following code is where I need your help please, it is for the detail page, when someone click on a city, this page shows the attractions of each city as a list. In this page, I wanted to be able to save the attractions as favorite that can be shown in another page.

```
class Detail extends StatefulWidget {
  final Cities cities;
  Detail(this.cities);
  @override
  _DetailState createState() => _DetailState();
}
class _DetailState extends State<Detail> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.cities.city),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                widget.cities.city,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: widget.cities.attractions.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Card(
                      child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(widget.cities.attractions[index]),
                  ));
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I need your help please to add this feature "save attractions as favorite". I need all saved attractions to be shown in a one **"saved attractions page"** irrespective of which city it belong to.

Can someone help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the example that I have made.
Following is the json that I have added I have just changes the data to your understanding

```
[
   {
       "city": "Canada",
       "attractions": [
           "Niagara Falls: An Elegant View",
           "Whistler: Your Perfect Ski Resort"
       ]
   },
   {
       "city": "Germany",
       "attractions": [
           "Berlin",
           "Munich"
       ]
   }
]
```

Model class from the json you provided:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final cities = citiesFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

List<Cities> citiesFromJson(String str) => List<Cities>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Cities.fromJson(x)));

String citiesToJson(List<Cities> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Cities {
    Cities({
        this.city,
        this.attractions,
    });

    String city;
    List<String> attractions;

    factory Cities.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Cities(
        city: json["city"],
        attractions: List<String>.from(json["attractions"].map((x) => x)),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "city": city,
        "attractions": List<dynamic>.from(attractions.map((x) => x)),
    };
}
```

This is the main ui and the miplementation

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Index(),
    );
  }
}

class Index extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _IndexState createState() => _IndexState();
}

List data;
List<Cities> citylist = List();
List<Cities> citysavedlist = List();
int index;

class _IndexState extends State<Index> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: listView(),
    );
  }

  Future<String> fetchData() async {
    String data =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("json/parse.json");
    final jsonResult = json.decode(data);
    this.setState(() {
      jsonResult
          .forEach((element) => citylist.add(new Cities.fromJson(element)));
    });
    return "Success!";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  listView() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: citylist == null ? 0 : citylist.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[_buildRow(index, citylist)],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRow(index, citylist) {
    final bool alreadySaved = citysavedlist.contains(citylist[index]);
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, left: 5.0, right: 5.0),
      child: Card(
        child: ListTile(
            title: Text(citylist[index].city, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0)),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                alreadySaved ? Icons.star : Icons.star_border,
                color: alreadySaved ? Colors.blue : Colors.blue,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (alreadySaved) {
                    citysavedlist.remove(citylist[index]);
                  } else {
                    citysavedlist.add(citylist[index]);
                  }
                });
              },
            ), //subtitle: Text(subtitle),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => Detail(citylist[index])));
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _pushSaved() {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute<void>(
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          final Iterable<ListTile> tiles = citysavedlist.map(
            (Cities pair) {
              return ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    pair.city,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Detail(pair)));
                  });
            },
          );

          final List<Widget> divided = ListTile.divideTiles(
            context: context,
            tiles: tiles,
          ).toList();
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Saved Suggestions'),
            ),
            body: ListView(children: divided),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Detail extends StatefulWidget {
  final Cities cities;
  Detail(this.cities);
  @override
  _DetailState createState() => _DetailState();
}

class _DetailState extends State<Detail> {
  List<String> attractionsSavedList = List();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getData();
  }

  /* 

  This is done using the shared Prefrences where the saving structure is String

  This is where key is the unique user id, this is because if you logout with another user then this will differentiate the user and get the string based on it. 

  I have saved  a Map<String,List<String>> as String encoded it and while using it decode the string which will give you the map.
   */

  getData() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var stringvalue = sharedPreferences.getString("Id");
    print(stringvalue);
    if (stringvalue != null) {
      Map<String, dynamic> newMap = json.decode(stringvalue);
      print('This is the city selected : ${newMap[widget.cities.city]}');

      var newlist = newMap[widget.cities.city];
      if (newlist != null) {
        newlist.forEach((element) {
          print(element);
          attractionsSavedList.add(element);
        });
      }
    } else {
      print('No values to show');
    }

    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.cities.city),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => SavedAttractions()));
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Saved Attractions',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                widget.cities.city,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: widget.cities.attractions.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  final bool attractionsExists = attractionsSavedList
                      .contains(widget.cities.attractions[index]);
                  return Card(
                      child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(widget.cities.attractions[index]),
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            SharedPreferences _prefs =
                                await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

                            setState(() {
                              if (attractionsExists) {
                                attractionsSavedList
                                    .remove(widget.cities.attractions[index]);

                                String uniqueid = _prefs.getString("Id");

                                Map<String, dynamic> mapvalue =
                                    json.decode(uniqueid);

                                List list = mapvalue[widget.cities.city];

                                String stringtoRemove;

                                list.forEach((element) {
                                  if (element ==
                                      widget.cities.attractions[index]) {
                                    stringtoRemove =
                                        widget.cities.attractions[index];
                                  }
                                });

                                if (attractionsSavedList.length == 0) {
                                  list.remove(stringtoRemove);

                                  if (list.length == 0) {
                                    mapvalue.remove(stringtoRemove);
                                    _prefs.setString(
                                        "Id", json.encode(mapvalue));
                                  }
                                } else {
                                  list.remove(stringtoRemove);
                                  mapvalue.remove(stringtoRemove);
                                  
                                  mapvalue[widget.cities.city] = list;

                                  _prefs.setString("Id", json.encode(mapvalue));
                                }
                              } else {
                                print(
                                    'It does not exist in the list ${attractionsSavedList.length}');
                                attractionsSavedList
                                    .add(widget.cities.attractions[index]);

                                var uniqueId = _prefs.getString("Id");
                                if (uniqueId != null) {
                                  Map<String, dynamic> newMap =
                                      json.decode(uniqueId);
                                  if (attractionsSavedList.length > 0) {
                                    print(widget.cities.city);

                                    newMap[widget.cities.city] =
                                        attractionsSavedList;
                                    _prefs.setString("Id", json.encode(newMap));
                                  }
                                } else {
                                  if (attractionsSavedList.length > 0) {
                                    Map newMap = Map();
                                    newMap[widget.cities.city] =
                                        attractionsSavedList;
                                    _prefs.setString("Id", json.encode(newMap));
                                  }
                                }

                                /*  {
                                  widget.cities.city: attractionsSavedList
                                }; */

                                attractionsSavedList.forEach((element) {
                                  print(
                                      'This is the list after adding  $element');
                                });
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          icon: Icon(
                            attractionsExists ? Icons.star : Icons.star_border,
                            color:
                                attractionsExists ? Colors.blue : Colors.blue,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ));
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SavedAttractions extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SavedAttractionsState createState() => _SavedAttractionsState();
}

class _SavedAttractionsState extends State<SavedAttractions> {
  List<String> attractionsList = List();
  bool _isLoading = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getSavedAttractions();
  }

  getSavedAttractions() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    String value = preferences.getString('Id');

    Map<String, dynamic> newMapVAlue = json.decode(value);

    newMapVAlue.forEach((key, value) {
      value.forEach((elements) {
        attractionsList.add(elements);
      });
    });

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _isLoading
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: attractionsList.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Card(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(attractionsList[index]),
                  ),
                );
              }),
    );
  }
}

List<Cities> citiesFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Cities>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Cities.fromJson(x)));
String citiesToJson(List<Cities> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Cities {
  Cities({
    this.city,
    this.attractions,
  });

  String city;
  List<String> attractions;

  factory Cities.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Cities(
        city: json["city"],
        attractions: List<String>.from(json["attractions"].map((x) => x)),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "city": city,
        "attractions": List<dynamic>.from(attractions.map((x) => x)),
      };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. No, I don't want it through api, it should be locally like what I already have for cities.

Comment: Just check out the example and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you very much Sagar for the help and support. Can I ask you one favor please. Can you add shared preferences to the first list, (list of cities).

Comment: How do want me to implement it

Comment: I suppose you implement it as you did for the attractions.

Comment: It seems that the current code miss the saving functionality when the app is closed. That is what shared preferences bring to the app , saving the favorite even if the app is closed.

Comment: Not yet, I am looking for your support please, I have created another question for that, this is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62777493/7122164?stw=2

Comment: I am working on it, will post the code by end of the day.

Comment: Thanks, highly appreciated

Comment: Hi Mr. Sagar, I am waiting for the answer please